# Why i have no clutch

Tags: nissan, clutch, 350z

I changed the clutch,pressure plate and throwout bearing bled the slave and still no clutch all new and air free nothing it almost goes in gear but if i turn the screw to push more it pops the slave out

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you give us a little more information? What year is your 350z? How is it different now than before you put the new clutch in? Is it not allowing you to put it into gear, or when you release the pedal you get nothing? What exactly is going on? Please edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: It's not clear from what you have written but I'm going to guess that you mean the clutch does not release when you press the pedal.  You mentioned the slave but what about the master?  Did you bleed it?  Are you sure the slave and master are working properly?

Comment: Did you make sure the pressure plate slid freely on the gearbox input shaft splines? If it does not then you get problems and the only solution is to take the box out again...

Comment: I think its the slave pin because it pops out the slave piston and leaks

Comment: Sounds like you might have missed a part or installed something incorrectly when putting in the throwout bearing or the clutch arm inside the bellhousing. If you take off the slave cylinder, is the end of the clutch arm where you expect it to be, just a mm beyond the slave piston? If you push on it with a screwdriver, does it move in (it should not move more than 2mm or so until it is very hard to push)?

Comment: The arm barely moves it almost goes in gear after bleeding but not quite if i try adjusting the threads on the master cylinder it pops the piston out the slave